# get color from hexadecimal

Tags: c#, .net, colors

So I have the following code below:

```
public System.Drawing.SolidBrush thisPen = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Red);
```

Currently, the pen is set to the color red, but how can I set it to a custom hex color?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  [ColorTranslator.FromHtml()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var c =  System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
var thisPen = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ColorTranslator.FromHtml()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml(v=vs.110).aspx) function to create a color from hex color code:

```
System.Drawing.Color c =  System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF0000"); // Red
public System.Drawing.SolidBrush thisPen = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(c);
```

You can also use this:

```
ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF0000")
```

Comment: Not sure why you added this 5 minutes after @dotctor's essentially identical answer.

Comment: @yeah.. i didn't notice it.. honestly... don't upvote this if you feel this is completely copied.